# Windows app with SSRS report in Windows 7

Tags: windows, authentication, windows-7, reporting-services

I was having an issue several months ago where I could not run an SSRS report through my Windows app because an older version of my passwer was being stored on my machine. I have recently upgraded to Windows 7 and now I get this error:

"Source: Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common
Method: GetSecureMethods
Message: The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.
Stack Trace: at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.GetSecureMethods()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.IsSecureMethod(String methodname)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.SetConnectionSSLForMethod(String methodname)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.LoadReport(String Report, String HistoryID)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ServerReport.GetExecutionInfo()
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ServerReport.SetParameters(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at InvoiceTracking.Reports.ReportInvoice.ReportInvoice_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
Target Site: System.String[] GetSecureMethods()
Data: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal"

I have had several coworkers try it on their machines as well with the same results. Any suggestions?

Comment: Two questions. First, if you run the application elevated (right click, run as administrator) does it work? Second, have you explicitly added yourself as a user to the database, or do you have access to all the databases because you're an administrator?

Comment: There is no option to run the application as administrator. I have admin access to all the databases. I moved my reports to a different server that has SQL2008-R2 and they seem to be working fine.